# efficient method to read and store data which is in JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, twitter, time

```
tweets_data = []
print('Opening file')
tweets_file = open('twitter_data.txt') #Its a file which has twitter data in JSON
start_time = time.time()
print('List generation in process')
for line in tweets_file:
   try:
      tweet = json.loads(line)
      tweets_data.append(tweet)
   except:
      continue
tweets_file.close()
print(len(tweets_data))
```

I'm using the above code to create a list which as twitter data (approx 3GB obtained through twitter api stream) but my program is running for more than 3hrs. I need an efficient way to do this by as I want to use this list for constructing a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you move your try except clause into a generator function such as this it might help:

```
def readline(tweets_file):
    for line in tweets_file:
        try:
           tweet = json.loads(line)
           yield tweet
       except:
           continue
```

Doing this makes it so it wont create a list, so you can't do len() on it, but you can still iterate over it without it needing to build a whole list in memory. As you loop over the generator it will producde one result at a time. If you still wanted a len, you could convert it to a list such as:

```
len(list(readline(tweets_file)))
```

Or you could loop over the generator and count such as:

```
counter = 0
for json_result in realine(tweets_file):
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure

```
tweets_data = []
print('Opening file')
tweets_file = open('twitter_data.txt') #Its a file which has twitter data in JSON
start_time = time.time()
append = tweets_data.append
print('List generation in process')
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        append(tweet)
    except:
        continue
tweets_file.close()
print(len(tweets_data))
```